# Authenticate user with pem certificate in keycloak rest api

Tags: authentication, keycloak

I am running keycloak using docker with an intention to authenticate user via rest api.
Currently, my configuration includes using grant_type=password along with client-id and client-secret to authenticate a client.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8079/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=234k23jk42j23i4u23iwerwlekrjwl'
--data-urlencode 'username=thor' \
--data-urlencode 'password=thor' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password'
```

I have set to use signed jwt for my client for which I have a PEM file.

**How do I supply PEM file in REST API to get access_token for the user ?**

[image]

Comment: I don't see client secret in your curl

Comment: To my understanding I thought we don't need client secret for signed jwt @JanGaraj